# Redirect an output command to a variable or file?

Tags: python, command-line, output

I'm trying to write a python script that will allow me to take the output from a command and to put that into a file or variable (Preferability  a variable).

In my code, I have redirected the output to a `StringIO()` object. From that, I want take the output a command and to put it into that `StringIO()` object.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import sys

old_stdout = sys.stdout

result = StringIO()
sys.stdout = result

# This will output to the screen, and not to the variable
# I want this to output to the 'result' variable
os.system('ls -l')
```

Also, how do I take result and put it into a string?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running shell command from python and capturing the output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import subprocess
sp = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, _ = sp.communicate()
print "Status:", sp.wait()
print "Output:"
print output
```

Comment: In my real code, I'm not using `ls -l`. I'm using the command `find *`. When I use `find *` in place of `ls -l` from the code you have in your comment, it doesn't give anything, though when I go to the normal command line, it outputs everything normal. When I use `ls -l` it works fine. Suggests?

Comment: You can use the `Popen()` argument `shell=True` and give it a string to be executed. Or you could use `['find', '.']` which should essentially be the same, more or less.